# How to mearge first & last 'xref' element value

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, xquery, xslt-2.0

**We required the first 'xref' element as it with label/attributes and concat the label of the last 'xref' with first one. And rest other 'xref' will be drop off, Can anyone look into that and suggest?**

**XML Input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xref-group>
<xref id="SL116633052-196250" scope="external" type="pdf" format="pdf"
    href="Images/1166_1.pdf">Maintenance Update 2017-21</xref>
<xref id="SL116633052-196250" scope="external" type="pdf" format="pdf"
    href="Images/1166_2.pdf">Maintenance Update 2017-22</xref>
<xref id="SL116633052-196250" scope="external" type="pdf" format="pdf"
    href="Images/1166_3.pdf">Maintenance Update 2017-23</xref>
<xref id="SL116633052-196250" scope="external" type="pdf" format="pdf"
    href="Images/1166_4.pdf">Maintenance Update 2017-24</xref>
</xref-group>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<xref id="SL116633052-196250" scope="external" type="pdf" format="pdf" href="Images/1166_1.pdf">
```

Maintenance Update 2017-21 through Maintenance Update 2017-24

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xref-group/xref">
    <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::xref)">
        <xsl:copy-of select="not(preceding-sibling::xref)"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:text> through </xsl:text>
    <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::xref)">
        <xsl:copy-of select="not(following-sibling::xref)"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Reference URL :** https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eixh2wW/1

Comment: @michael.hor257k, Can you please look into that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not specified which output you expect for an `xref-group` that does *not* have the range format. The following templates deal with the range case, defined as all `xref` children having the same `id` attribute (your question is silent about what exactly constitutes a range):

```xml
<xsl:template match="xref-group[count(xref) > 1 and
                                not(xref/@id != xref/@id)]/xref"/>
<xsl:template match="xref-group[count(xref) > 1 and
                                not(xref/@id != xref/@id)]/xref[1]"
              priority="1">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/> through <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::xref[last()]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, We required the first 'xref' elment as it with lable and concatnating the lable of the last 'xref'. like as i.e. 
<xref id="SL116633052-196250" scope="external" type="pdf" format="pdf" href="Images/1166_1.pdf">
Maintenance Update 2017-21 through Maintenance Update 2017-24
</xref>

Comment: That's what my solution proposal provides.

Comment: Thank you! Rest other 'xref' need to delete and also 'xref-group' does not required.